# Many UI-Bootstrap-Datepickers on page loads very slowly - can I use a single instance and move element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have many rows displayed using 'ng-repeat'. Each row has 2 x UI-Bootstrap-Datepickers. When there are many rows, the loading of the page gets really slow.

I would like to just use a single datepicker and then move it dynamically under the field that the user has clicked into, or possibly load the directive on click and unload it again after a selection has been made.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

```
<li ng-repeat="ticket in data.tickets">

    <div ng-click="openAddStartCal($event, ticket)" ng-hide="currentTicketUpdating == ticket.TicketId && currentParameterUpdating =='startCal' && startCalSaving == true">
                        <input type="text"
                               starting-day="2"
                               show-button-bar="false"
                               show-weeks="false"
                               class="form-control addTicketDateInput"
                               datepicker-popup="dd MMM"
                               ng-model="ticket.StartDate"
                               ng-change="saveEditStartDate(ticket)"
                               is-open="checkStartOpened(ticket)"
                               min-date=""
                               max-date="'2015-06-22'"
                               datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                               date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                               ng-required="true"
                               close-text="Close" />
                    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ng-switch or ng-if. Ng-switch/ng-iff will actually remove whatever is inside it from teh DOM until the condition evaluates to true.

For example:

```
<li ng-repeat="ticket in data.tickets">
    <div ng-click="openAddStartCal($event, ticket);ticket.openCal = !ticket.openCal" ng-hide="currentTicketUpdating == ticket.TicketId && currentParameterUpdating =='startCal' && startCalSaving == true">
          <div ng-if="ticket.openCal">
                    <input type="text"
                           starting-day="2"
                           show-button-bar="false"
                           show-weeks="false"
                           class="form-control addTicketDateInput"
                           datepicker-popup="dd MMM"
                           ng-model="ticket.StartDate"
                           ng-change="saveEditStartDate(ticket)"
                           is-open="checkStartOpened(ticket)"
                           min-date=""
                           max-date="'2015-06-22'"
                           datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                           date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                           ng-required="true"
                           close-text="Close" />
                </div>
        </div>
</li>
```

Notice the `ticket.openCal = !ticket.openCal` addition to the ng-click and then using that in ng-if. (Btw, ig you have something useful for this in openAddStartCal, you can just use that.)

Alternatively, you can also use something like empty ng-include (until the row-click):

```
<li ng-repeat="ticket in data.tickets">
    <div ng-click="openAddStartCal($event, ticket);ticket.openCal = !ticket.openCal" ng-hide="currentTicketUpdating == ticket.TicketId && currentParameterUpdating =='startCal' && startCalSaving == true">

      <div ng-include=""></div>
</li>
```

Then you set the ng-include variable when there is the click event.

Comment: I was curious so I plunked it - http://plnkr.co/edit/LyLdqurWyrRhrF7ZmoDB?p=preview

Comment: That's actually amazing :) They have something like that on SO now too, but not sure if you can do something this neat in it.

Comment: I am also trying to implement the same approach for my application as shown in plunker but I ran into few other issue. While clicking on the datepicker button, it is taking time for span to be removed from dom and input textbox to be added.Why is it so ?