# Many AngularUI Datepicker making page performance low

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-datepicker

I am working with AngularUI Datepicker.I have seprate partial views each having ng-repeat .There I am using AngularUI-Bootstrap-Datepickers and it is making page load really slow.

I followed this answer: 
[Many UI-Bootstrap-Datepickers on page loads very slowly - can I use a single instance and move element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197281/many-ui-bootstrap-datepickers-on-page-loads-very-slowly-can-i-use-a-single-ins)

But I got few other issues.In this approach we are using separate ng-if to switch from span to textbox. But switching between them is taking considerable amount of time which make it visible to user that we are playing with textboxes.(check Image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxZXQ.png )

I also followed this : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/3666/commits

But I am unable to integrate the changes and successfully run the datepicker.

Is there any reliable solution to this issue?

Comment: Hard to know what's going on without seeing more. My guess is that you have lots of watchers on the page and so the $digest cycle is taking a long time. You should try to minimize watchers in order to maintain performance.

Comment: The PR you mentioned was included in the 0.13.1 release under [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/b72efed56f68e9e5dbed934df7f47e0b5c94242c) commit.  What version of the library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[Many UI-Bootstrap-Datepickers on page loads very slowly - can I use a single instance and move element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197281/many-ui-bootstrap-datepickers-on-page-loads-very-slowly-can-i-use-a-single-ins)

```
   <p class="input-group">
    <span class="form-control" ng-if="!date.opened1">{{date.data1|date:format}}</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
           ng-if="date.opened1" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="date.data1"
           is-open="date.opened1"
           datepicker-options="dateOptions"
           close-text="Close"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, date,1)">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
</p>
```

code

```
$scope.open = function($event,date,i) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    date['opened'+i] = !date['opened'+i];
 };
```

[Plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/LyLdqurWyrRhrF7ZmoDB)